# htaccess is redirecting everything except from the root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I have a htaccess set-up as such:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new\.co\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Which, to me at least, should forward everything to new.co.uk

However it does not forward the root (which I want it to) so if you go to

```
www.old.co.uk
```

Nothing happens but

```
www.old.co.uk/a
```

Redirects to `new.co.uk`

Comment: Is this the only rule OR you have some other rule also?

Comment: Only rule... And there are no other files for the domain

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```